# Scrolling background image by mouse wheel

Tags: background, scroll, parallax

I need to make script that will change background image position by only scroll of a mouse. Document doesnt have width to be scrolled. It a content slider. The idea is to make parallax scrolling like in Android.
 Here is the code I am going to use:

```
$(window).bind("load resize scroll",function(e) {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("body").filter(function() {
        return $(this).offset().top < (y + $(window).height()) &&
               $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() > y;
    }).css('background-position', '0px ' + parseInt(-y / 6) + 'px');
});
```

How to make 'body' background to move when mouse wheel is scrolled?

Comment: Good for you.  Happy mouse wheeling!

Comment: What do you mean? is it hard? or impossible?

Comment: What I mean is that I do not see a question.  There is no question mark.

Comment: How to make 'body' background to move when mouse wheel is scrolled? Here is the goal.